# Making a cart in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a cart that checks if the right item have been placed inside. I dont know how i would build this the best way. The way i would build this is by making the cart check for gameobjects names and then check if its the right one.

The result of doing it the way i would have done it, Is alot of werid names and also making it hard to add more items due to it almost being fully hardcoded.

First i thougt of using tags but i already use them for my pickup system and since you cant have more then one for some reason i cant.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try storing the products in a List. Each product would (inherit maybe) from the a Product.cs and each time you add one product in the cart, update the List.
Also you can check if is the right one before calling the cartList.Add() based on a string field(or int maybe?) in the Product.cs.

You can also store all the Product.cs in the Start method, either in a List or a dictionary, and check if it’s the right one before adding to cartList.

Sorry for the vague answer, I fast-typed on my phone. I hope this helps.

Comment: I read your answer and its a really good ide. But i decided to go with making a custom tag system. by the way you answer was not vague at all and it was well detaild thanks for the ide.